# Delphi - Como ler planilha inteira do Excel para dentro de um ClientDataSet?

Tags: delphi

Fala pessoal! Estou tendo um problema ao ler dados de uma planilha do Excel pra dentro de objetos OleVariant. Minha procedure até lê a planilha certinho, só que ela só lê até a linha 3162 e a planilha tem 3272 linhas. Será que tem algum limite pra ler essa planilhas de Excel? O código está abaixo:

```
procedure TfrmEnvioDeEstoque.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Excel, Livro, Planilha, Range: OleVariant;
  Dados: Variant;
  i: Integer;
  j: Integer;
const
  xlDown = -4121;
begin
  inherited;
  opnPlanilha.Execute();

  Excel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  try
    Livro := Excel.WorkBooks.Open(opnPlanilha.FileName);
    Planilha := Livro.WorkSheets.Item['Sheet1'];

    Range := Planilha.Range['A2', Planilha.Range['O2'].End[xlDown]];
    Dados := Range.Value;

    cdsProdutos.DisableControls;
    cdsProdutos.EmptyDataSet;
    cdsProdutos.First;

    for i := 1 to VarArrayHighBound(Dados, 1) do
    begin
      cdsProdutos.Append;
      cdsProdutosmarcar.AsString       := 'T';
      cdsProdutosreferencia.AsString   := Dados[i, 1];
      cdsProdutosnome.AsString         := Dados[i, 2];
      cdsProdutossku.AsString          := Dados[i, 3];
      cdsProdutosatt1.AsString         := Dados[i, 4];
      cdsProdutosatt2.AsString         := Dados[i, 5];
      cdsProdutosatt3.AsString         := Dados[i, 6];
      cdsProdutosquantidade.AsInteger  := StrToInt(Dados[i, 7]);
      cdsProdutospreco.AsFloat         := StrToFloat(Dados[i, 8]);
      cdsProdutosvariante.AsString     := Dados[i, 9];
      cdsProdutospeso.AsString         := Dados[i, 10];
      cdsProdutoslargura.AsString      := Dados[i, 11];
      cdsProdutoscomprimento.AsString  := Dados[i, 12];
      cdsProdutosaltura.AsString       := Dados[i, 13];
      cdsProdutostags.AsString         := Dados[i, 14];
      cdsProdutoscodigoBarras.AsString := Dados[i, 15];
    end;

  finally
    Range := Unassigned;
    Planilha := Unassigned;
    Livro := Unassigned;
    Excel.Quit;
    Excel := Unassigned;

    cdsProdutos.First;
    cdsProdutos.EnableControls;
  end;

end;
```

A minha planilha tem as colunas de A a O, por isso eu seto um range para os Dados. Desse jeito eu consigo popular os campos do meu ClientDataSet do jeito que estou fazendo acima. Se tiver um jeito mais fácil de fazer isso, gostaria de saber. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Experimente inicializar uma variável com o conteúdo de VarArrayHighBound(Dados, 1) e veja se está com o valor correto.

Comment: se na planilha a coluna "O" tiver uma célula em branco antes da linha 3272 o método `End(xlDown)` vai parar na última linha com conteúdo... use esse método quando tiver certeza que todas as linhas estão com as células preenchidas para aquela coluna, usando a dica do @RicardoAlvesCarvalho vc pode facilmente verificar isso